# how to improve logistic regression model in python

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, statistical-significance, categorical-data, model-evaluation

I have 1 million raw data points, and I dropped 2 independent variable because the have over 80% missing value.

All my variables are categorical except for "age" which I scaled between -1 and 1. Remaining were turned into dummy variables.

i want both of the F1 scores to be high [0.94093409 0.56259895] specially in the 0.5625

here is my features

sex: 1 for female and 2 for male.
age: of the patient.

classification: covid test findings. Values 1-3 mean that the patient was diagnosed with covid in different
degrees. 4 or higher means that the patient is not a carrier of covid or that the test is inconclusive.

patient type: type of care the patient received in the unit. 1 for returned home and 2 for hospitalization.

pneumonia: whether the patient already have air sacs inflammation or not.
pregnancy: whether the patient is pregnant or not.

diabetes: whether the patient has diabetes or not.

copd: Indicates whether the patient has Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease or not.

asthma: whether the patient has asthma or not.

inmsupr: whether the patient is immunosuppressed or not.

hypertension: whether the patient has hypertension or not.

cardiovascular: whether the patient has heart or blood vessels related disease.
renal chronic: whether the patient has chronic renal disease or not.

other disease: whether the patient has other disease or not.

obesity: whether the patient is obese or not.

tobacco: whether the patient is a tobacco user.

usmr: Indicates whether the patient treated medical units of the first, second or third level.

medical unit: type of institution of the National Health System that provided the care.

intubed: whether the patient was connected to the ventilator.

icu: Indicates whether the patient had been admitted to an Intensive Care Unit.

date died: If the patient died indicate the date of death, and 9999-99-99 otherwise.

```
  #Creating the dependent variable “DEATH” 
covid['DEATH']= np.where(covid['DATE_DIED']=="9999-99-99",0,1)
covid['DEATH'].value_counts()
print('Data Shape :', covid.shape)
covid.info()

#Number of Unique Values by column

for col in covid.columns : 
    print('{:<20} => {:>10}'.format(col, len(covid[col].unique())))

#Percentage of missing values    
print('Percentage of missing values')
for col in covid.columns :
    print('{:<20} => {:>10.2f}%'.format(col, len(covid[(covid[col]==98) | (covid[col]==99) | (covid[col]==97)])/len(covid)*100))

covid['INTUBED'].value_counts()
covid['ICU'].value_counts()
covid['PREGNANT'].value_counts()

#Getting rid of the missing values of features except "INTUBED", "PREGNANT", "ICU"¶

cols = ['PNEUMONIA','DIABETES', 'COPD', 'ASTHMA', 'INMSUPR','HIPERTENSION', 


           'OTHER_DISEASE', 'CARDIOVASCULAR', 'OBESITY','RENAL_CHRONIC', 'TOBACCO']
    for col in cols :
        covid = covid[(covid[col] == 1)|(covid[col] == 2)]
    # Converting process according to inference above
    covid.PREGNANT = covid.PREGNANT.replace(97,2)
    
    # Getting rid of the missing values
    covid = covid[(covid.PREGNANT == 1) | (covid.PREGNANT == 2)]
    
    covid.drop(columns=["INTUBED","ICU","DATE_DIED"], inplace=True)

 from pandas.core.indexing import convert_from_missing_indexer_tuple

from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
scaler = RobustScaler()
covid.AGE = scaler.fit_transform(covid.AGE.values.reshape(-1,1))

#dummy

corr=covid.corr()

#Creation of the first line in spearman correlation matrix:

corr["first line"]=["USMER","MEDICAL_UNIT","PATIENT_TYPE",                    
"PNEUMONIA","AGE","PREGNANT","DIABETES","COPD","ASTHMA","INMSUPR","HIPERTENSION","OTHER_DISEASE","CARDIOVASCULAR","OBESITY","RENAL_CHRONIC","TOBACCO","CLASIFFICATION_FINAL","GENDER","DEATH"]

corr1=0
var=[]
while (corr1< len(corr['DEATH'])):
     if (corr["DEATH"][corr1]>0.1 or corr["DEATH"][corr1]<-0.1 ):
          var.append(corr["first line"][corr1])
     corr1=corr1+1

print(" The variables that have a significant correlation with the dependant variable are: ",var)   


# Replace values in data by "Value"_variable
df9=covid
other_variables=['AGE','DATE_DIED','DEATH']
col5=df9['USMER']
i=0
for col5 in df9:
  
  if (col5 not in other_variables and col5 in var): 
    for i in range(1,98):
      head1=df9[col5].head(0)
      head_concate=str(i)+"_"+ str(head1) 
      df9[col5]=df9[col5].replace(i,head_concate)
 
df12=covid["AGE"]
col6=df9['USMER']
for col6 in df9:
  if col6 not in other_variables and col6 in var : 
       Dummy=pd.get_dummies(df9[col6], drop_first = True)
       df12=pd.concat([df12,Dummy],axis = 1)  

y= covid['DEATH']
x= df12

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(train_x,train_y)
y1_pred=logreg.predict(test_x)

print('Logistic regression model accuracy:{:.2f}'.format(logreg.score(test_x,test_y)))
print("Logistic Regression F1 Score :",f1_score(test_y,logreg.predict(test_x),average=None))
print("Logistic Regression F1 Score :",f1_score(test_y,logreg.predict(test_x),average='weighted'))
print('precision before undersampling  : %.2f' % precision_score(test_y, logreg.predict(test_x),average='weighted' ))
print('recall before undersampling : %.2f' % recall_score(test_y, logreg.predict(test_x),average='weighted'))


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

#undersampling only for the training data
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0)
x_train_rus,y_train_rus = rus.fit_resample(train_x,train_y)

logreg_under = LogisticRegression()
logreg_under.fit(x_train_rus,y_train_rus)
print("Logistic Regression Accuracy after undersampling :",logreg_under.score(test_x, test_y))
print("Logistic Regression F1 Score after undersampling :",f1_score(test_y,logreg_under.predict(test_x),average=None))
print('F1_score: %.2f' % f1_score(test_y, logreg_under.predict(test_x),average='weighted'))
print('precision after undersampling  : %.2f' % precision_score(test_y, logreg_under.predict(test_x),average='weighted' ))
print('recall after undersampling : %.2f' % recall_score(test_y, logreg_under.predict(test_x),average='weighted'))

sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(test_y, logreg_under.predict(test_x)), annot=True, fmt=".0f")
plt.title("Logistic Regression Confusion Matrix",fontsize=18, color="red");
```

the results are

```
     Percentage of missing values
USMER                =>       0.00%
MEDICAL_UNIT         =>       0.00%
PATIENT_TYPE         =>       0.00%
DATE_DIED            =>       0.00%
INTUBED              =>      81.62%
PNEUMONIA            =>       1.53%
AGE                  =>       0.03%
PREGNANT             =>      50.28%
DIABETES             =>       0.32%
COPD                 =>       0.29%
ASTHMA               =>       0.28%
INMSUPR              =>       0.32%
HIPERTENSION         =>       0.30%
OTHER_DISEASE        =>       0.48%
CARDIOVASCULAR       =>       0.29%
OBESITY              =>       0.29%
RENAL_CHRONIC        =>       0.29%
TOBACCO              =>       0.31%
CLASIFFICATION_FINAL =>       0.00%
ICU                  =>      81.64%
GENDER               =>       0.00%
DEATH                =>       0.00%
Logistic regression model accuracy:0.94
Logistic Regression F1 Score : [0.96769158 0.51907982]

precision before undersampling  : 0.93
recall before undersampling : 0.94


Logistic Regression Accuracy after undersampling : 0.8959226207949275
Logistic Regression F1 Score after undersampling : [0.94093409 0.56259895]

precision after undersampling  : 0.95
recall after undersampling : 0.90
```

and I did a Random Forest model that also had poor results.

I only did under sampling on training set because I do not want my model to be biased. Help me if you have another method or another machine learning model that will improve the results i will be grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you want to undersample to remove bias? That sounds like an introduction of bias to me, and one that involves a loss of precious data.

Comment: without the balancing the data the results of F1 score is [0.94093409 0.56259895] , 0.94 represent the probability of the people who are not dead and 0.5625 who are dead , the problem of my model is  When we look at the F1 Score it says that we predicted the patients who survived well but we can't say the same thing for dead patients. that what i want to improve

Comment: i appreciate your help